# Quantum Erasure - what causes the phase difference in the two interference patterns observable at Do?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, double-slit-experiment, causality, non-locality, quantum-eraser

In the Delayed Quantum Erasure experiment, I understand that the interference patterns that you would see at Do is associated to the entangled photons that eventually arrive at D1 or D2 (which-way info erased). To actually see the interferences, you first remove the photons related to D3 and D4, but you still have to sort out the photons that arrived at D1 from D2 because there are two interference patterns, one related to photons arrival at D1 the other at D2 and they are exactly out of phase, hence not distinguishable until that D1/D2 sort out is completed. Why is there this phase difference? I just have not seen that explained anywhere. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the two color lines head toward D1, one path has an extra reflection. Sometimes the light does not reflect but is transmitted through. When this happens it does not change phase.
Example:
D1 receives a red line after one reflection at(Mb). D1 receives a blue line after two reflections at (Ma and BSc). They are out of phase.
In addition to that the red lines final source (where it last reflected from) is at BSc which is closer than the blue lines final source (where it last reflected from) at Ma.
The attached sketch is similar where I have the final two sources labeled A and B

[image: This sketch is similar where I have the two sources labeled A and B.]

Comment: There's not enough detail, I guess in the experimental setup write-up to see this. I do see now that the reflection in the diagram from the blue line at Ma to BSc seems to be after the line goes through BSc so it reflects at the exact same surface as the red line from Mb to BSc so there is that "passing-through-BSs" difference, but isn't that still a reflection so the number of reflections should be equal? Can you say a little more? 

I get that reflections change phase. Thank you for your response!

Comment: @ParityViolator The blue line only reflects at MA. The blue line is transmitted through every other obstacle. The phasing only reverses at reflection and not when transmitted through the medium.

Comment: D1 receives red line after one reflection and blue line after two reflections. D2 receives blue line after one reflection and red line after two reflection.

Comment: I'm thinking the last comment answers the question as to what is different with respect to what happens at D1 vs D2.

Comment: Another question that has occurred to me, if a photon that goes through the slit always produces a hit at D0. Do all the hits at D1, D2, D3 and D4 add up to the number of hits at D0? I have some mild confidence 1/4th of the number of hits at D0 will be the number that occurs at D3 and at D4. But would 1/4th also occur at D1 and D2? The beam splitter at BSc could make it so the photons that go down red and blue go to different detectors half the time, so you would get 1/8th at D3 and D4. I have to confess, I'm not very good at guessing how the superposition of states would be handled at BSc.

Comment: Thanks for your solution to phase reversal!